# i have got a little cache with setting a string into a registry value

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying this:

```
@echo off
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ /v siavash /t   REG_SZ /d "c:arda1" /f 
start explorer.exe
pause
```

but i'm getting this in registry
c:arda1
without double quotes 
did anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what is expected. The quotes are used to quote the string you want to add, they are mostly used when the string has a space, but work the same even when they don't.

If you want to add quotes around the string then try this

```
"\"c:arda1\""
```

The `\"` is the escape character for the `"` sign, and the outside quotes are just quoting the whole string as normal.

Hope this helps.